# Can the spacing of menu bar apps be modified in macOS Big Sur and later?

Tags: macos, big-sur, menu-bar, ui

It's much too wide, which is a problem if you use a lot of menu bar apps.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the terminal run:

```shell
defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain NSStatusItemSpacing -int 6
defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain NSStatusItemSelectionPadding -int 6
```

Logout/relogin required to apply changes.

A value of 6 for both spacing and padding looks good to me, but your mileage may vary. You can decrease the padding down to 0 if you want an even tighter layout.

Run the following to revert back to default settings:

```shell
defaults -currentHost delete -globalDomain NSStatusItemSelectionPadding
defaults -currentHost delete -globalDomain NSStatusItemSpacing
```

Comment: Awesome. Possible credits: https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/16lpfg5/hidden_preference_to_alter_the_menubar_spacing/

Answer (score 19):

Actually, there appears to be some way to do this, since the newest version of [Bartender](https://www.macbartender.com/Bartender4/) allows you to change or remove spacing in the menu bar. The app costs $15 (but offers a four-week free trial).

To change the spacing with Bartender, install the app, open the preferences window, and under "General" change "Menu bar item spacing" to "Small Spacing." After logging out and back in (or, if that doesn’t work, rebooting), the changes should take effect.

Answer (score 7):

It is the approach Apple is taking, getting the menu bar items wider. Some conspiracy theories are stating that it might be the beginning of touch screen macs since the new UI is a lot more touch friendly. You can watch "Snazzy Labs" video about it while Big Sur was in beta. I believer it was called "Big Sur's Secret" or smt...

Back to your question, no. At this point, until a developer gets his hands on a 3rd party app or apple listens to its customers resisting the change, you cannot change any of the Big Sur spacings.

Addition: At the time of writing this answer, there were no software capable of doing such thing. However, as the answer above me mentioned a newer version of "Bartender" capable of such thing. This answer is obsolete.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give feedback to Apple about this and recommend others who feel the same do so too.

Answer (score -1):

You can hold <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> and drag some of the icons to remove them to reduce the amount you have in the menubar. With some of the new additions Apple has put in, there is some redundancy and you no longer need some of them. For example - you no longer need the Sound menubar item. I know it's not a huge help - but it seems these days every little bit counts, lol..

Good luck!

Comment: Which version of macOS and which icons. Option drag just seems to open them on BigSur

Comment: @mmmmmm it's Cmd-Drag, not Opt